# How to use vertex locations of one object as instance scale for other object in GN?

Tags: vertices, transforms, geometry-nodes

Given is one object (the main object) with n vertices and an `Instance on Points`-Node is applied to it to make all vertices e.g. to icospheres (of the same size at the specific vertex locations).

**I now want to scale the icospheres individually using another object (with also n vertices) whose vertex locations should be used for the individual scaling.**

I tried it with an `Object Info`-Node, but it provides only the object location not the vertex location. Using a `Capture Attribute`-Node on the `Object Info`-Node like so, does not work either (but maybe I used it wrong):

[image]

With this setup, the object disappears, because the scale is all (0,0,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an "Attribute Transfer" node here to get the vertex positions from the second mesh. An attribute in mesh A will just give you zero values when you try to use it directly for mesh B.

Set the transfer node to "Index" mode. It will use the regular Index input by default, no need to connect anything to it. Since your meshes have the same number of vertex that works just fine. Use the position attribute to transfer the vertex positions from the scale mesh (the "Location" output of Object Info is just the single location of the object, not what you want here).
[image: Transfer vertex positions from another mesh]

Comment: That works! Thanks! Just a small follow-up question: There is no ```Input>Scale```-Node, so it would not be (as easily) possible to copy the scale of object ```Scales``` to object ```Cylinder```, right?

Comment: The Object Info scale output is overall scale of the whole object, just like Location is only the origin of the object. Individual vertices don't have a native scale attribute.
In 3.2 alpha builds you can just store an extra vector attribute in the Scales points if needed and then read it with a "Named Attribute" node.